# How to move Firebase realtime database child value into another child value in an android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to move Firebase realtime database child value into another child value in an android studio. ( points: 25 into totalpoints: from the same user uid.

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "8xNAsCfc3Afta2lPHHsMWHEOw8C2" : {
      "points" : 25,
      "users" : "umar"
    }
  },
  "wFinal" : {
    "8xNAsCfc3Afta2lPHHsMWHEOw8C2" : {
      "totalpoints" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

I want this

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "8xNAsCfc3Afta2lPHHsMWHEOw8C2" : {
      "points" : 0,
      "users" : "umar"
    }
  },
  "wFinal" : {
    "8xNAsCfc3Afta2lPHHsMWHEOw8C2" : {
      "totalpoints" : 25
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do something like, you get the value from points 25, after that, set the value to wFinal

Comment: Have you tried anything in your side?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman special thanks for answering my question I have successfully implement the method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move Firebase child from one node to another in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456443/how-to-move-firebase-child-from-one-node-to-another-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comment, something like this.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userUid).child("points").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            long points = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
        //transfer the value
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wFinal").child(userUid).child("totalpoints").setValue(points);
        //set the value at Users to 0
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userUid).child("points").setValue(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Comment: Lots of love and special thanks for answering my question I have successfully implemented this method.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is at the time you do a `.setValue(points)` to your `Users - userId` reference, you also do a `.setValue(points)` at the `wFinal` Reference

Make sure to add a complete listener after `.setValue()` to know when each transaction completes.

**Pseudocode**

```
userRef.child(userId).child("points").setValue(0).addOnCompleteListener {

  onComplete(...) {
    wFinalRef.child(userId).child("totalPoints").setValue(points);
  } 

}
```